# Query with Regex object checking specified string pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am learning C# and 
I have a small testing program where the console should receive a digit as input as and not an alphabetic character.

```
string inputString;

        string pattern = "[A-Za-z]*";
        Regex re = new Regex(pattern);

        inputString = Console.ReadLine();

        while(re.Match(inputString).Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please stick to numerals");
            inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(inputString);
```

Problem is the compiler doesn't differentiate between an alphabetical character or a numeral.

Any suggestion perhaps
The code seems to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `string pattern = "[A-Za-z]*";` will also match 0 characters because of the `*` quantifier.

If you only want to check if there is a letter in the string, just use

```
string pattern = "[A-Za-z]";
```

but of course this is only matching the ASCII letters. The better approach is to use Unicode properties

```
string pattern = @"\p{L}";
```

`\p{L}` will match any Unicode code point with the property "Letter".

**NOTE:**

I hope you are aware that this is not checking for only digits, its checking if there is a letter in the input. This will of course accept characters that are not digits and not letters!

If you want to **check for only digits** you should go for @musefan's answer or use regex this way

```
string inputString;

string pattern = @"^\p{Nd}+$";
Regex re = new Regex(pattern);

inputString = Console.ReadLine();

while (!re.Match(inputString).Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please stick to numerals");
    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine(inputString);
```

`\p{Nd}` or `\p{Decimal_Digit_Number}`: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.

See [www.regular-expressions.info/unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for more information about Unicode properties.

The next alternative is to **check if there is "not a digit"** in the input:

```
string pattern = @"\P{Nd}";
...
while (re.Match(inputString).Success) {
```

The you need to change only the pattern, `\P{Nd}` is the negation of `\p{Nd}` and will match if there is one non digit in the input.

Comment: I might have overall preferred to check for all numeric rather than look for characters: `"^[0-9]+$"` (my RegEx isn't great though so this could be wrong)

Comment: @musefan I updated my answer with the checking for digits alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a fan of RegEx overuse, so here is an alternative you could always try...

```
public bool IsNumeric(string input)
{
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
       if(!char.IsDigit(c))
       {
          return false;
       }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can use this as follows...

```
while(!IsNumeric(inputString))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Please stick to numerals");
   inputString = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

...of course if you want RegEx I am sure someone will sort you out shortly ;)

---

With thanks to Eli Arbel via the comments below, you can even shorten this method if you are willing/able to use [LINQ extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx):

```
public bool IsNumeric(string input)
{
   return input.All(x => char.IsDigit(x));
}
```

Comment: @EliArbel: Nice call, I have not used `.All` before. I added a bit more information to my question to reflect your comment

Comment: +1 for the alternative solution. Now with the lambda expression it looks much nicer than looping over all characters.